# Stored Endpoint IP Address after Network Configure Changes in RMI

Tags: macos, rmi, rmiregistry

I've got a RMI server running on a mac. Once I changed the server IP and restart the Application and clients, then clients keep connect to the old ip address with right bind and lookup address. I really have no idea what went wrong because the program is working on another linux server just with different port.

What the remote object clients got is `Proxy[MinervaInterface,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[192.168.0.104:51815](remote),objID:[40d99efb:140ba232cec:-7fff, 6333954213550330995]]]]]`

which 192.168.0.104 is the old IP and it should be 10.0.1.104

I've check the host file and my code, there is no anything like `192.168.0.*`

Please help, Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have confirmed this is a server registry problem. But I have already restarted the server. I did't remember what else did I do to the registry. Is there any way to set it manually?

**UPDATE**

I rune this code on that server `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`, it returned `192.168.0.104`, that can explain where this address came from. But there is no such address on the server now

**SOLVED**

I found java use a hostname to lookup localhost address, that hostname is not `localhost` and have not been updated by `OS X Server` for some reason. I updated the record from OS X Server console and solved this annoying problem.

NEVER THOUGHT ABOUT THAT

Comment: Did you restart the Registry?

Comment: @EJP I have restarted the server. But how to restart the registry?

Comment: Stop it and start it again? What's the problem?